How to change the main theme colors of a C# MAUI application during runtime?
My MAUI application is split into a login page and two shells for each type of user (normal, the theme is blue, and administrative, which is themed red), and I want not only the things inside the shell to be color-themed, but also the stuff outside of it, like the base colors. From the beginning, a lot of colors are set to blue in Resources/Styles/Colorx.xaml and Platforms/Android/Resources/Values/colors.xaml, which is fine because both the login page and the normal user shell are supposed to be blue. However, the administrative part looks bad if some parts are red and some are blue, so I want to change these colors to red if the user has administrative permissions. Let's say, UserIsAdministrative() is being triggered. What do I need to do to change the resources?
This is what my Colors.xaml and Android/colors.xaml look like (I left out the other irrelevant colors)
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <!-- Note: For Android please see also 
Platforms\Android\Resources\values\colors.xml -->
    <Color x:Key="AdministrativeColor">#E3004F</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NormalColor">#0076BD</Color>

    <Color x:Key="Primary">#0076BD</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Tertiary">#0076BD</Color>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TertiaryBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Tertiary}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>

Android Part

<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0076BD</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0076BD</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#0076BD</color>
</resources>

When UserIsAdministrative() is triggered, all the colors should change to #E3004F / AdministrativeColor.
I hope you understand what I mean, thanks!

Do you mean you want to change the Colors in colors.xml of Android platform at runtime?

If you declared BindableProperty IsAdministrativeProperty in a global singleton service you could swap your colors using either a DataTrigger or BoolToObjectConverter.
